# EL3, Sum of a field in a collection?

Tags: lambda, el

I've a collection and I want to iterate over it and make the sum of a specific attribut / field.

In java, it would simply be :

```
list.stream().mapToInt(o->o.field).sum();
```

But when I try that in my EL I get

> Unable to find method [mapToInt] with [1] parameters

I'm using Expression language 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution here in case it helps someone else :

```
list.stream().map(o->o.field).sum()
```